# How to enable cipher suites not in JSSE

Tags: java, security, sockets, ssl, encryption

I need my Java client which its job is to makes SSL connection with SSL servers to be able to support the following chipher suites:

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
```

The problem is that when I the Java supported cipher suites using: `socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();`

I did not find them. How can I add these two ciphers into the JSSE supported cipher suites? Please, clarify.

Comment: You can't. If it isn't in JSSE, there is nothing to enable. You could try another provider, such as BouncyCastle. But any cipher suite not in JSSE isn't likely to be supported by the peers either.

Comment: @EJP BC supports it I guess. But, will I need to change my code that starts the handshake? I could not find good resources on how to use BC. In particular, how to edit the cipher suite list in my code using BC? appreciate if I can get any hints.